# How the distortion is made for ads printed on the grass of a stadium

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, problem-solving, 3d

We all already watched a soccer match. And on the grass, there is advertising that are made to look like a 2d image. For those who don't what I'm talking about, here is an image:

[image: GrassAds]

And I wondered how to create this effect. My idea was to compute the shadow of a plane containing the ad like this:

[image: Blender rendered image]

So now, my question is how to compute every corner of shadow of the plane and how to recreate this effect. I want something that takes the point of the camera and every corner of the plane to give 4 point which will be the 4 corner of the shadow.

You can give a Python program instead of an expression if you want. Just in case if you think it's more appropriate.

Comment: They don't appear super realistic; the vertical edges don't have the same (or even any?) vanishing point as the dashed lines they're presumably parallel to.

Comment: I don’t see much, if any, any distortion at all. They look to me like rectangles that are simply superimposed on the image of the field, albeit with a bit of alpha so that the texture shows through a bit.

Comment: @amd it's normal, on a camera, they aren't supposed to look distorted, it's just an illusion. See this [image](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-reNJAUnwGxM/VZ9tjYrrk2I/AAAAAAAAADY/urJs65M8J1k/w960-h600/GrassAds%2BStadiums.jpg)

Comment: In that case, it’s likely a simple perspective projection, about which you can found out more than you want to know with a simple Internet search. The basic idea is the same as yours, except that instead of casting a shadow onto the field you cast it “forward” onto an image plane perpendicular to the camera’s view axis.

Comment: Ok, I’ll take a look @amd

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood youe question. This is a distorted projection called $Anamorphosis$. We see them everyday, like for example those warning text on roadways. There is a free software which can do $Anamorphosis$ in many different ways.

Comment: Which software? Could you add a link?

Comment: @ArthurGuiot, this site is very useful and it has the like to download the software.https://anamorphicart.wordpress.com/page/2/